# how do I pass context to for .. in loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var that = this, k,
    colors = ['#468966','#FFF0A5','#FFB033B','#B64926','#8E2800'];
    data = [];

    that.k=0;
    for (var i in answers){
            data.push({
                key: i,
                color: colors[k%5],
                values: []
            });
            answers[i].forEach(function(answer,index){

                that.data[k].values.push({
                    label: 'user_'+index,
                    value: answer.answer
                });
            });
        that.k++;
    }
```

I want to be able to access `data[]` and `colors` and `k` inside the `for (var i in answers)` loop. How do I pass the outer context to this function? Or is there another alternative?

I might have omitted some info: this is inside a function, so the code looks like:

```
  var createChartData = function(answers){
    var that = this, k,
    colors = ['#468966','#FFF0A5','#FFB033B','#B64926','#8E2800'];
    data = [];

    k=0;

    for (var i in answers){
            data.push({
                key: i,
                color: colors[k%5],
                values: []
            });
            debugger;
            answers[i].forEach(function(answer,index){

                that.data[k].values.push({
                    label: 'user_'+index,
                    value: answer.answer
                });
            });
        k++;
    }
return data;
}
```

But I think this should be irrelevant. Inside the `for` loop I cannot access `k` or `colors`, surprisingly I can access `that`. I am very confused...

OK, I might have had some other issue, because now it works, I will check it again later to figure out where was my problem.

Comment: "Scoping": data, colors, and k are always accessible in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Those variables are already accessable inside the foreach callback as [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) variables

The only change I might look at is to remove the usage of variable `that` in favor of `thisArg` param of [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
var k,
    colors = ['#468966', '#FFF0A5', '#FFB033B', '#B64926', '#8E2800'];
data = [];

this.k = 0;
for (var i in answers) {
    data.push({
        key: i,
        color: colors[k % 5],
        values: []
    });
    answers[i].forEach(function (answer, index) {

        this.data[k].values.push({
            label: 'user_' + index,
            value: answer.answer
        });
    }, this);
    this.k++;
}
```